# How to create a partition in remote ApacheDS, LDAP server?

Tags: windows, ldap, centos, apacheds

I know how to create a partition in local ApacheDS instance from [this article](http://directory.apache.org/apacheds/basic-ug/1.4.3-adding-partition.html). Current problem is I don't know how to create a partition in remote ApacheDS.

I am accessing remote ApacheDS server(in CentOS) from Apache Directory Studio(in Windows).

Any help would be appreciated.

ApacheDS 
Version: 2.0.0-M14

Apache Directory Studio
Version: 2.0.0.v20130517

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if your problem is that you can't access the remote instance or another.
But if you want to create a partition follow this ["guide"](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.apache.directory.user/5937).
ApacheDS seems to have a very bad tutorial.

Comment: This guide may work, but anyways it is a crap. Your answer is the only valuable here.

Answer (score -1):

Contrary the other answers, here I explain the real problem. The sad truth is the following:

**You can't manipulate the partitions of a non-local Apache Directory Server with Apache Directory Studio.**

You can't even do this with a locally running one. The only what you can do, are the Apache Directory Server partitions running inside your Apache Directory Studio.

However, there is a workaround for the problem. It is particularly useful, if you are using linux, or at least you have a cygwin by the hand.

The Apache Directory Server has a complex directory structure, full with small files, partially binary and partially text data.

**This data structure doesn't contain any filesystem references, so you can freely clone it.**

Create an LDAP server inside your Apache Directory Studio. Open its properties. You get a popup form. Inside this form, you will see some like this:

> Location /your/home/directory/.ApacheDirectoryStudio/.metadata/.plugins/org.apache.directory.studio.ldapservers/servers/e56640c7-70ed-4eed-921c-75c475117a11

This is what you want!

This is the directory structure, where your local ApacheDS is running!

And you can now easily synchronize this data structure, ideally with a simple `rsync` command, into your server or back!

So,

- You create the new Apache Directory Server instance inside the Apache Directory Studio
- Your check its properties
- You stop it, and synchronize your server-side server directory into your this one! For example, `rsync -va --delete you@your.server.com:/srv/apacheds/instance/ /your/home/directory/.ApacheDirectoryStudio/.metadata/.plugins/org.apache.directory.studio.ldapservers/servers/e56640c7-70ed-4eed-921c-75c475117a11`
- You play with the partitions as you wish
- You synchronize it back.

**Of course if you are playing with the Apache Directory Server file structure on such a low, file-system level, the server needs to be stopped!**